# Is the Batch Geocoder Nearing End of Life?

Tags: here-api

The current Batch Geocoder Introduction page states:

"Note: This service is no longer being actively developed. We will only provide critical fixes for this service in future. Instead, you can use the new Geocoding and Search API v7 service."

I do not see mention of geocoding large dataset of addresses in the "Geocoding and Search API v7" API Reference.  As a matter of fact, the "Geocoding and Search API v7" API Reference webpage is titled, "Geocoding and Search API v1 (1.0)" which is also strange.

Is the Batch Geocoder nearing end of life?  If so, does any documentation exist that describes the new approach to geocoding large datasets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not at all..now v7 is the newer API with more features and will keep on offering new features and will be actively developed. The older version is no more actively developing. Also v7 API offers to use Geocoder API with our platform (Cloud based product). The additional benefits are as follows :

```
HERE Geocoding and Search leverages the freshness, breadth and depth of HERE Map Content
It provides a rich and comprehensive set of capabilities that enable you to build applications that your end-users need and desire.
It is fully integrated in the HERE Platform to enable you to create, process, ingest and search your own data sets. (Note: Bring Your Own Data capabilities are only available to customers with a HERE Platform Workspace license.)
```

Comment: When I look at the Geocoding and Search API online documentation, all the examples are still using v1 instead of v7.  The Batch Geocoder examples use v6.2 (and have since I began using the Here API). I guess these will be updated soon since I see that it is "IN MATINANCE" (which it did not used to say).  I'll mark this as the answer.  Thanks for the response!