# Batch Geocoder "In Maintenence"

Tags: here-api

on the [Batch Geocoder](https://developer.here.com/documentation/batch-geocoder/dev_guide/topics/introduction.html) page, there is a banner at the top that says it is "In Maintenence" and that in the future we should use the Geocoding and Search API v7 service. Does the Geocoding and Search API also have batch geocoding capabilities? If not, if I am geocoding the same number of addresses in Geocoding and Search API as I would be with the Batch Geocoding API, would the pricing be the same? I asked this question to marketing, but they redirected me to this page. Thanks.

Comment: This question has already been answered here: [Is the Batch Geocoder Nearing End of Life?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61367697/is-the-batch-geocoder-nearing-end-of-life)

Comment: Thanks @Tomas.  However, in that post, the answer isn't very clear as to whether there will still be a Batch Geocode service in v7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "in maintenance" was added to the Batch Geocoder accidentally and has been removed. Eventually this feature will be added to v7 as well. Until then (and for some time after), you can continue to use Batch Geocoder API as usual. Rest assured that it is not going away and sorry for the confusion caused.